# Creating SP document library feature

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In need to create a feature that will create a document library under subsites based on the condition. Some sub sites should have 3 doc library and some should have just 1.

Can I just have 1 feature that will create library based on the condition or should there be 7 features to create document library?

Comment: You can create one feature in which you have the logic to check the conditions and create document library accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can define list template in your solution. As the exact number of lists on each site is dynamic you need to create list instances in your code.

Typically it's done in feature receiver if you need to create them once while feature is activated.

Or you can implement web event receiver in your solution and create list instances from your template when new site is created.